# Identifying which value in where clause is incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL kung-fu is not strong.  I want to know if I can identify which value of a WHERE clause is incorrect. 
So say I execute the following SQL statement....

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.myTable WHERE col1 = 'ABC' and col2 = 123
```

I want to be able to identify either that the value 'ABC' for col1 doesn't exist OR that the value 123 for col2 does not exist. 
This would be within a single query, as I want to avoid two queries if possible. 
Where I execute the first, and if rows exist then I execute the second if no rows then I can derive that col2 is wrong.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.myTable WHERE col1 = 'ABC' 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.myTable WHERE col1 = 'ABC' and col2 = 123
```

I have considered

```
SELECT 1 as qRow, col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.myTable WHERE col1 = 'ABC' 
UNION 
SELECT 2 as qRow, col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.myTable WHERE col1 = 'ABC' and col2 = 123
```

and based on the qRow value i can determine which value is missing within the table, but wanted to now if there was any other solution

Comment: if you have a single query, how will you use the information that either of the values does not exist? you could simply use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: Technically I need the second query, where BOTH exist within a record.  The first query would be to identify that col1 is the culprit.

Comment: Values in where clause are not incorrect.  Not clear what you you want.  "'ABC' for col1 doesn't exist OR that the value 123 for col2 does not exist"  "execute the first, and if rows exist then I execute the second if no rows then I can derive that col2 is wrong"  "based on the qRow value i can determine which value is missing within the table"  Inconsistent and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find where col1 is not ABC or col2 is not 123, you can do this:

```
SELECT  col1 ,
        col2 ,
        col3
FROM    dbo.myTable
WHERE   col1 <> 'ABC'
        OR col2 <> 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
CASE 
   WHEN col1 = 'ABC' and col2 = 123 THEN 'both_true'
   WHEN col1='ABC' THEN 'col1_true'
   ELSE 'col2_true'
END AS value_check

 FROM dbo.myTable WHERE col1 = 'ABC' or col2 = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I think probably you can use `NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM dbo.myTable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from dbo.myTable 
where col1 = 'ABC' or col2 = 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `OR` instead of `AND` you could add a `CASE` statement to show the matching column:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
       CASE WHEN col1 = 'ABC' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as Col1Match,
       CASE WHEN col2 = '123' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as Col2Match
FROM dbo.myTable 
WHERE col1 = 'ABC' OR col2 = 123
```

### [Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4281/3)

You will see in the sample fiddle, that rows are only returned where one or both items match.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, case when col1 <> 'ABC' then 'X' end as 'MissingCol1Abc',
case when col2 <> 123 then 'X' end as MissingCol2
FROM dbo.myTable 
WHERE col1 = 'ABC' OR col2 = 123
```

Or did you mean you want to know when the column is null?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, case when is null col1 then 'X' end as 'MissingCol1Abc',
case when col2 is null then 'X' end as MissingCol2
FROM dbo.myTable 
WHERE col1 = 'ABC' OR col2 = 123
```